# a different kind of unsupported operand issue (python 3)

Tags: python, string, operands

Hello I'm new to python and programming in general (just started last night!) and I've written a tiny program thats pasted below:

```
name = str(input("please state your name: ")) 
print ("Welcome %s, your doomesday weapon of impolite mutant pigeons is ready for launch") %name
```

However this keeps returning this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prog.py", line 2, in <module>
print ("Welcome %s, your doomesday weapon of impolite mutant pigeons is ready for launch") %name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Now I know that the usual answer to this kind of problem is to convert my input from a string to an integer and adjust the used operand type to match. However in this case, I actually want to use the input in string form so wheres the issue at?

P.S I'm using Ideone.com for compiling this code.

Comment: `print()` must include the whole string you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

```
... launch" %name)
```

instead of

```
... launch") %name
```

Answer (score 0):

The string-formatting `%` needs to go inside the `()`; the `print` function returns `None`, and you're trying to format the result.

Assuming you're using Python 3, your initial call to `str()` is also unnecessary; `input()` returns a string. (If you're using Python 2, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, which also returns a string.)

Comment: Thank you good sir! Your alteration fixed my program. I would vote you up but I don't have enough reputation points :P.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question:

```
name = "andy"
print "Welcome %s, your doomesday weapon of impolite mutant pigeons is ready for launch" %name
```

If this works (then you are using Python 2), if it doesn't it is becuase in Python 3 you need to enclose print statements in brackets, and will get a **`SyntaxError`**.

```
name = "andy"
print ("Welcome %s, your doomesday weapon of impolite mutant pigeons is ready for launch" %name)
```

The second is that Ideone.com does not accept user input, and hence the string `name` is left as None (which is not a string) which explains the `TypeError`.

```
name = None
print ("Welcome %s, your doomesday weapon of impolite mutant pigeons is ready for launch" % name)
```

Comment: Well the program works but now I've run into another issue. For some reason when I make the following statement: if name == "John", I get an error saying that my syntax is invalid. If you can offer a solution to this plus the negative version (name != "John"), it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RationalMystic Could this be because you are missing a `:` at the end of the line? (it's hard to see without the full code.) You should look into a Python tutorial e.g. Dive into Python. Also, you should upvote and accept helpful answers :).

Comment: lol I know what you're trying to say but I don't have enough reputation points to actually upvote people yet. I would if I could.